# Fetching data dynamically when data is stored in Dynamic data type

Tags: c#, json, wcf, object, dynamic

A WCF service is returning a JSON data which is consumed by client application This JSON data is caught in an Object and its Deserialized and stored in Dynamic Data type as shown A WCF service is returning a JSON data which is consumed by client application This JSON data is caught in an Object and its Deserialized and stored in Dynamic Data type as shown

```
 dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(retVal.ToString());
```

where retVal is my Json Data which is

```
         {"txtEmpNoTo":123,"Name":"Leonel Messi"}
```

and the number of data may vary

I don't know what is property present and values as well. How can i fetch the data without knowing the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your `json` without knowing the property name by using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Just `convert` your `json` to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. Please check below code.

CODE:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Example #1");
        string retVal = "{\"txtEmpNoTo\":123,\"Name\":\"Leonel Messi\"}";
        Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(retVal);
        foreach(var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("Example #2");
        retVal = "{\"txtEmpNoTo\":123,\"Name\":\"Leonel Messi\",\"Team\":\"FC Barcelona\"}";
        values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(retVal);
        foreach(var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("Example #3");
        retVal = "{\"txtEmpNoTo\":123,\"Name\":\"Leonel Messi\",\"Team\":\"FC Barcelona\",\"Squad Number\":10,\"Date of Birth\":\"24-Jun-1987\"}";
        values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(retVal);
        foreach(var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

You can run and check it in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VgCMhR).